# Show that $(G,+,*)$ as follows is a commutative ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group with unity, say $e_G$. Define the binary operation $*$ as: for all $x,y \in G, x*y = e_G$. Show that $(G,+,*)$ is an commutative ring.

My attempt:

For the associativity of $*$:
Let $x,y,z \in G$. Then, we have

\begin{align*}
(x*y)*z &= e_G * z \\
&= e_G \\
&= x * e_G \\
&= x * (y*z)
\end{align*}

Hence, * is associative.

Am I true for the associativity above?

If true, then $(G,*)$ is a semigroup.

Now, for the distribution laws:

Left:
Let $x,y,z \in G$. Then,
\begin{align*}
x*(y+z) &= e_G \\
&= e_G + e_G \\
&= x*y + x*z
\end{align*}
since $y+z \in G$.

Right:
Let $x,y,z \in G$. Then,
\begin{align*}
(x+y)*z &= e_G \\
&= e_G + e_G \\
&= x*z + y*z
\end{align*}
since $x+y \in G$.

Hence, the distribution laws is hold.

Now, for all $x,y \in G$ we have $x*y = e_G = y*x$.

Hence, $(G,+,*)$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: Your proof of associativity of $*$ is correct,. But note that distributivity does *not* follow from associativity; you need to prove it as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks Sir!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin What about now, Sir?

Comment: This multiplication is commutative, so you really only need to check one of the distributivities, not both; but in any case, they are both wrong as written: third line does not follow from the second line. And you should really use parentheses throughout, since you don’t have a precedence of operations without a ring structure (which you have not yet established).

Comment: This looks good. I'd suggest writing $e_G = e_G + e_G$ in the proof of distributivity for clarity though. I'm not sure why $e_G = e_G * e_G$ is relevant there.

Comment: Ooops, a typo. Thanks Sir!